# angularjs and html populated options of a select dinamically

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays, select

i should populate options of a select dinamically with an array.

Values of array are values that i retreive from a server through the method http.post, i post it a value and for any value that i post, i retreive a different array so i can't know the length of the array.

I'm able to use http.post for having the array, than i copy it in another variable and then from another page (html) i need to populate options of a select with values of the array, it works if i use `<option>{{array[0]}}</option>` etc. but i can't know the length of the array so this method isn't applicable.

**ANGULAR**:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.data = {};

    $scope.submit = function(){
        var link = 'http://localhost/ShuttleFIX/api.php';
        $scope.var = "prova";
        $http.post(link, {username : $scope.data.username}).then(function (res){
            $scope.response = res.data;
            $scope.array = [];
                $scope.array[0] = $scope.response[0];
                $scope.array[1] = $scope.response[1];
        });
    };
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<select id="select">
    <option>{{array[0]}}</option>
    <option>{{array[1]}}</option>
</select>
```

Can someone help me?

Thank's

Comment: [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions), or [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) are possibles ways of achieving it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In controller

```
$http.post(link, {username : $scope.data.username}).then(function (res){
   $scope.response = res.data;
});
```

In HTML

```
<select id="select">
    <option ng-repeat="option in response" value="{{option}}">{{option}}</option>
</select>
```